# Trying to have my Raspberry Pi in two seperate networks: One WiFi, one ethernet, but the internet stopped working after ethernet setup

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, ethernet, raspberry-pi

First of all, I am quite new to Raspberry Pi, Linux, and Networking. I started by setting up my RPi 3 to connect to my local WiFi (I always access the RPi via WiFi using RealVNC). The internet worked perfectly from the beginning. Then I learned to control an Arduino via Serial.

Now I intend for the RPi to control several Arduinos within a closed (no internet) ethernet (just a small switch that connects the devices). I managed to connect the first Arduino via ethernet and got them communicating.

**The problem:** without changing anything regarding the WiFi, I can no longer access the internet since the ethernet setup. The RPi is still in the WiFi network (I still access it via RealVNC) and I can see it on the router under WLAN devices.

I tried all kinds of things using the help from ChatGPT to no avail. I checked the `dhcpcd` and interface files and ran every check that was suggested, including restarts and disabling firewalls.

The separate ethernet seems to work fine, and the Wifi works perfectly, but I can't access the internet anymore (I tried the Chromium browser, to download updates via programs, and `ping google.com` via terminal but I only got 100% package loss: no data returned).

Any help is appreciated. Please keep in mind that I am quite the noob and might need little more detailed answers :)

Comment: You need to check your routing & dns.